# Apple Catcher game

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm trying to create an apple catcher game... But the code I've gotten so far is really buggy. First of all the point counter don't match the apples caught. Same with the computer points. The apples and the "basket" also glitch into each other, you will see it in the demo. How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated :)

Demo-link #1: https://files.itslearning.com/data/134/17123/k4.html

Let me know if the link doesn't work^^ :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var spillerPoeng = 0;
  var pcPoeng = 0;


  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");



  var Kloss = function(xPos, yPos) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
  }

  Kloss.prototype.tegnKloss = function() {

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 100, 50);

  }

  Kloss.prototype.flyttVenstre = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";

    ctx.clearRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 150, 80);

    this.xPos = this.xPos - 20;

    ctx.fillRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 100, 50);
  }

  Kloss.prototype.flyttHoyre = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";

    ctx.clearRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 150, 80);

    this.xPos = this.xPos + 20;

    ctx.fillRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 100, 50);
  }


  var Kule = function(xPos, yPos, radie) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.radie = radie;
    this.farge = getRandomColor();

  }



  Kule.prototype.tegn = function() {


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radie, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.farge;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

  };

  Kule.prototype.fjernKule = function() {

    ctx.clearRect(this.xPos - 11, this.yPos - 11, this.radie * 2 + 4,
      this.radie * 2 + 4);


  }


  $("#venstre").click(function() {

    kloss1.flyttVenstre();
    kloss1.tegnKloss();
  });

  $("#hoyre").click(function() {
    kloss1.flyttHoyre();
    kloss1.tegnKloss();
  });



  function loop(objekt) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      if (objekt.yPos < 480) {

        objekt.fjernKule();

        objekt.yPos = objekt.yPos + 10;

        var sjekk = sjekkTreff(kloss1, objekt);
        if (sjekk == 1) {
          spillerPoeng++;
          document.getElementById("spillerPoeng").innerHTML =
            spillerPoeng;
        } else if (sjekk == 2) {
          pcPoeng++
          document.getElementById("pcPoeng").innerHTML = pcPoeng;
        }

        objekt.tegn();



        loop(objekt);
      }

    }, 300)


  }


  function randX(min, max) {

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

  }

  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    color += "00";
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    color += "00";
    return color;
  }





  var kuleListe = [];

  var maxKuler = 0;

  function settKuleListe() {

    setTimeout(function() {


      kuleListe[maxKuler] = new Kule(randX(10, 480), 0, 10);

      loop(kuleListe[maxKuler]);
      maxKuler++

      settKuleListe();

    }, 2000);

  }



  function sjekkTreff(obj1, obj2) {
    if (obj1.xPos < obj2.xPos && obj1.xPos + 300 > obj2.xPos && obj2.yPos > 450) {

      return (1);
    } else if (obj2.yPos > 450) {

      return (2);
    } else {


      return (3);

    }




  }


  var kloss1 = new Kloss(50, 450);
  kloss1.tegnKloss();



  settKuleListe();






});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
        </canvas>
</div>
<div>spiller poeng:
  <p id="spillerPoeng"></p>
</div>
<div>PC poeng
  <p id="pcPoeng"></p>
</div>

<br>
<div>
  <button id="venstre"> << </button>
  <button id="hoyre"> >> </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looked fun, so I tried to "improve" your code.

Here is one that works with arrow keys, try it and edit it as much as you want !

(And of course, I'm here if you have questions, but I think my code is pretty clear)

The code isn't finished yet, I thought letting some errors would help you improve yourself, so try to find them if you can ;)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const basketSpeed = 5;
const gravity = 2;

const basket = new Basket();
const apples = [];

const score = document.querySelector('#counter span');
let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => apples.push(new Apple()), 500);

let pressingLeft = pressingRight = false;

draw = function() {
  basket.draw();
  for (let apple of apples) { apple.draw(); }
}

animate = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();

function Basket() {

  this.width = 50;
  this.height = 10;
  
  this.x = (canvas.width / 2) - this.width / 2;
  this.y = canvas.height - this.height - 10;
  
  this.dx = 0;
  
  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    this.update();
  }
  
  this.update = function() {
    if(pressingLeft) { this.dx = -basketSpeed; }
    else if (pressingRight) { this.dx = basketSpeed; }
    else { this.dx = 0; }
    
    if (this.x + this.width + this.dx < canvas.width && this.x + this.dx > 0) { this.x += this.dx; }
  }
}

function Apple() {
  this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
  this.y = 0;
  
  this.radius = 10;
  
  this.dy = gravity;
  
  this.allowDraw = true;
  
  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    this.update();
  }
  
  this.update = function() {
    this.y += this.dy;
    if (this.x > basket.x && this.x < basket.x + basket.width &&
      this.y + this.radius >= basket.y
    ) {
      updateScore();
      apples.splice(apples.indexOf(this), 1);
    }
  }
}

updateScore = function() {
  counter++;
  score.innerText = counter;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
  pressingLeft = ev.keyCode === 37;
  pressingRight = ev.keyCode === 39;
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (ev) => {
  if (ev.keyCode === 37) { pressingLeft = false; }
  if (ev.keyCode === 39) { pressingRight = false; }
});
```

```css
canvas { background: #ddd; position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); }
#counter { display: inline-block; margin: auto; position: relative; top: 50px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="counter">Score : <span>0</span></div>
```

Comment: Well most of the questions I answer or just so simple or so undocumented by the OP, I should be the one thanking you :P And I only used knowledge I got from **[this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript)**, nothing more ! I highly advise you to look at this tutorial, it's very detailed

Comment: Is it possible for you to send me the code via a document? For some reason I cant seem to copy the code from here and run it from my computer...? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks again for the fiddle! Im still working on this little game, using your code. Which is great btw! Just one question, if I where to make the dots falling - turn them into pictures of coins for example. How would I do that? Dont need finished code. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Instead of creating circles, you should create images of coins, that's all ! The code remains the same, except for they "draw" function of the apple object. Canvas can draw images, so you should have no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you increment while doing the motion frames (3 times inside the box). I fixed the counters using a flag for calculated or not to increment. you should consider enhancing your game because not only the apple has to be within the basket bounds but also the passing through the opening of the basket.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var spillerPoeng = 0;
  var pcPoeng = 0;


  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");



  var Kloss = function(xPos, yPos) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
  }

  Kloss.prototype.tegnKloss = function() {

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 100, 50);

  }

  Kloss.prototype.flyttVenstre = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";

    ctx.clearRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 150, 80);

    this.xPos = this.xPos - 20;

    ctx.fillRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 100, 50);
  }

  Kloss.prototype.flyttHoyre = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";

    ctx.clearRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 150, 80);

    this.xPos = this.xPos + 20;

    ctx.fillRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, 100, 50);
  }


  var Kule = function(xPos, yPos, radie) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.radie = radie;
    this.counted = false;
    this.farge = getRandomColor();

  }



  Kule.prototype.tegn = function() {


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radie, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.farge;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

  };

  Kule.prototype.fjernKule = function() {

    ctx.clearRect(this.xPos - 11, this.yPos - 11, this.radie * 2 + 4,
      this.radie * 2 + 4);


  }


  $("#venstre").click(function() {

    kloss1.flyttVenstre();
    kloss1.tegnKloss();
  });

  $("#hoyre").click(function() {
    kloss1.flyttHoyre();
    kloss1.tegnKloss();
  });



  function loop(objekt) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      if (objekt.yPos < 480) {

        objekt.fjernKule();

        objekt.yPos = objekt.yPos + 10;

        var sjekk = sjekkTreff(kloss1, objekt);
        if (sjekk == 1 && !objekt.counted) {
          spillerPoeng++;
          objekt.counted=true;
          document.getElementById("spillerPoeng").innerHTML =
            spillerPoeng;
        } else if (sjekk == 2 && !objekt.counted) {
          pcPoeng++
          objekt.counted=true;
          document.getElementById("pcPoeng").innerHTML = pcPoeng;
        }

        objekt.tegn();



        loop(objekt);
      }

    }, 300)


  }


  function randX(min, max) {

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

  }

  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    color += "00";
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    color += "00";
    return color;
  }





  var kuleListe = [];

  var maxKuler = 0;

  function settKuleListe() {

    setTimeout(function() {


      kuleListe[maxKuler] = new Kule(randX(10, 480), 0, 10);

      loop(kuleListe[maxKuler]);
      maxKuler++

      settKuleListe();

    }, 2000);

  }



  function sjekkTreff(obj1, obj2) {
    if (obj1.xPos < obj2.xPos && obj1.xPos + 300 > obj2.xPos && obj2.yPos > 450) {

      return (1);
    } else if (obj2.yPos > 450) {

      return (2);
    } else {


      return (3);

    }




  }


  var kloss1 = new Kloss(50, 450);
  kloss1.tegnKloss();



  settKuleListe();






});
```